# SQL query to pull data from one table that matches single column data from second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables structured as such with the included data. Table STOCK:

[image]

Table TEMP:

[image]

I need to pull both columns of data from table STOCK that matches each pattern entry from table TEMP. The resulting table would look like:

[image]

These are just examples; my TEMP table contains 82 patterns while the STOCK table contains 750,000 entries. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select s.*, t.pattern
from stock s join
     temp t
     on s.partnumber like '%' + t.pattern + '%';
```